# How to make navbar background color width size align with navbar content with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a navbar using bootstrap 5 shown as below

[Navbar with full-width background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbAfP.png)

Below is the code

```css
.navbar a {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.nav-link {
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

body {
  background-color: #e4e6eb;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Style/style.css">
    <title>Frontend</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              <img src="Assets/TravelBuddy.png" alt="Logo" style="max-height: 40px;">
          </a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Package</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Testimony</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  Services
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="d-grid">
              <a class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mt-md-0 ms-lg-5" href="#" role="button">Login</a>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-/bQdsTh/da6pkI1MST/rWKFNjaCP5gBSY4sEBT38Q/9RBh9AH40zEOg7Hlq2THRZ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like the navbar background color width size is not full as above picture, but as shown below

[Navbar with non full-width background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd4ZM.png)

How can I achieve this?, thanks!

Comment: I'm certain that the background-color in the image hasnt been applied to the navbar itself but to the Title. The only other way to do it is by using linear-gradient which must be done as custom CSS though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve your desired style by...

1. Remove the `bg-light` class from the `<nav>` tag.
2. Add the `bg-light` class in the `<div>`
3. In CSS set

```
.navbar{
background-color: rgb(112, 112, 253)
}
```

Your code should look like this

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
            <div class="container bg-light">
```

[The Resulting Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7Kls.png)